# How to combine list of vector and a vector of labels as a data table in r

Tags: r, data.table

The length  of the list of vector and the vector of label should be the same. With length == 3 for example:

```
n <- list(c(1,2),c(6,7,8),c(10))
cat <- c("c1", "c2", "c3")
```

I want to make a data table in this form:

```
n      cat
1      c1
2      c1
6      c2
7      c2
8      c2
10     c3
```

Comment: It would be `data.table(n = unlist(n), cat)`, but your values in `cat` are not going to match and it look like you might have to manually specify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `stack` after setting the names of the `list` with 'cat' `vector`

```
out <- stack(setNames(n, cat))
names(out) <- c("n", "cat")
out
#   n cat
#1  1  c1
#2  2  c1
#3  6  c2
#4  7  c2
#5  8  c2
#6 10  c3
```

---

In `tidyverse`, this can be achieved with `enframe`

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
n %>%
  set_names(cat) %>%
  enframe(name = 'cat', value = 'n') %>%
  unnest(n)
```